# ssh connection from server through other server (A->B->C)

Tags: ssh, centos7, ssh-tunnel

I have 3 servers, lets call them A, B and C

Server C is behind a firewall and only server B can connect to it. Server B and C are under my control.

Now I want server A to connect to server C through server B:
A -> B -> C

The problem is I can't change the command on server A which is probably just a simple ssh user@B.

I'm trying to forward the incomming connection using the command option in authorized_keys:

```
command="ssh user@C" ssh-rsa KEY
```

Whenever A makes a connection to B, I can see that a connection is made to C but A doesn't seem to realize this and timesout.

I have tried to add options -t,-t -t, -T or -N to the ssh command but to no avail. Is there any way to foreward the ssh connection in a way that server A thinks he is communication with server B.

The connection between B and C need to be triggered when A makes the connection to B and closed when A closes the connection.

All authentication is done using keys.

[edit]

To clarify:
I can't control the command on Server A but as it is now, A does connect to B AND then B opens a connection to C. The problem here is dat A does not recognise that new connection. I think it doesn't get a prompt or something so that A knows there is a connection.

If I use this setup manually with

```
ssh user@B
```

it works and I'm directly logged in at C.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an SSH tunnel.

```
ssh -f user@B -L 2000:C:22
```

This connects to server B, directly goes to background with `-f` and then opens port 2000 on localhost with `L`. Everything that is send to this port on localhost is forwarded to port 22 on C. So once you entered this command you can do

```
ssh localhost -p 2000
```

Which will connect you to C.

## Update

Seems I misunderstood you, sorry. If you cannot change the command on A, you can still specify what should happen on login, by changing the `~/.bashrc` of the user.

Comment: This won't work. I can't specify the command on A. I can only enter the hostname, username and port. So I need to create the tunnel on server B at the moment A connects to B.

Comment: @Nin sorry that I misunderstood you. I made an edit. You can change the ~/.bashrc of the user so it does an ssh connect this way.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Please see my edit for more clarification (I hope ;:)

Answer (score 1):

In the home directory of the user in the server B you'd add a last line to the file `~/.login` (or create it if it doesn't exist) in order to run the second `ssh userc@hostC`.

Please, don't used `~/.bashrc`: while the former is used after logins, the latter is used for every bash execution, even the one in scripts starting with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: although I have put it in the autorized_keys file (so it will only be used for server A) it seems that A does not see the new connection. Please see my edit.

Comment: authorized_keys is to be used with the destination SSH server, not the originating one! I'd expect to see authorized_keys in servers B and C for this specific purpose, if needed.

Comment: yes, this is in authorized_keys on server B. It works, in that I can see that a connection is made to server C but server A does not see/use the new connection.